# search multiple keywords in each line of file using Nodejs file system?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, fs, file-read

I have a search criteria where user will search multiple keywords in a file , so below i have each line data from file ,now my `searchStr` that is array of keyrwords from client. So i want to check these search keyowrds in each line in the file if it matches push that line to `results`, In below code if you search only one keyword it will give you results but if you have mutilple keywords its not sending any response ? Any idea how can i achieve this task ?

search.js

```
/*Example of search String  
var searchStr = [{"text":"457383"},{"text":"requestPdr"}]
*/

     function asyncFiles(filesData) {
         async.eachSeries(filesData.logFiles, function(logfile, done) {
             // read file
             readStream = fs.createReadStream('./logs/' + filesData.searchEnv + '/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8')
             readStream.pipe(split())
                 .on('data', function(line) {
                     for (var i = 0; i < searchStr.length; i++) {
                         if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr[i].toLowerCase()) != -1)
                             //            parseLog(line, prevLine);
                             //            else prevLine = line;
                             var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
                         messageDateInfo = new Date(messageDateInfo).getTime();
                         searchStartDate = new Date(searchStartDate).getTime();
                         searchEndDate = new Date(searchEndDate).getTime();
                         if (messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0) {
                             // console.log("message date is within this time range");
                             results.push({
                                 filename: logfile.filename,
                                 value: line
                             });
                         }
                     }
                 });
             done();
         }, function(err) {
             if (err) {
                 console.log('error', err);
             }
             readStream.on('end', function() {
                 callback(results);
             });
             results = [];
         });
     }
```